# After SQL server service restarts waiting tasks comes down normal

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

For last few months we have observed that SQL server BUFFER LATCH is very high and at that very moment Waiting Tasks spikes up. During this time we ran SP_Blitz, Blitz_cache and BlitzFirst and found more or less all types of waiting are there. Once we restarts SQL server service then everything becomes normal. Again it spikes after 2-3 days so. We use SQL 2012 standard edition.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Don't "knee-jerk" react to waits, they're always there. Is your server performing slowly. Google "Paul Randal", he's written extensively about Waits on SQLSkills.com

Comment: when Waiting tasks are getting crossed above 50 then we encounter performance and Head Block occurs.